# Replace content of a div with an external php file in Laravel 3

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have an unordered list of movies being displayed from the Rotten Tomatoes API in a page called browse (using Laravel Framework). I am trying to use AJAX to load content into a div from a separate file that I have setup as a route called movie when the user clicks on the anchor.

In my routes file I have this:
    Route::get('browse', array('as'=>'browse', 'uses'=>'browse@index'));
    Route::get('movie', array('as'=>'movie', 'uses'=>'browse@movie'));

Browse View located at /application/views/browse/index.blade.php

```
$movies = $search_results->movies;
echo '<div id="browse">';
echo '<ul class="movieResults">';
  foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    echo '<div class="movieCard">'; 
    echo '<li><img src="'. $movie->posters->detailed .'"</li>';
    echo '<li class="movieCardInfo"><a href="movie" class="movie">' . $movie->title . '</a></li>'; // HERE'S WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM
    echo '</div>';
  }
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

Movie View located at /application/views/browse/movie.blade.php. I have dummy text for now

```
echo '<div class="details">';
```

echo '

test

';
    echo '';

Browse Controller

```
public $restful = true;
  public function get_index() 
  {
    return View::make('browse.index')
    ->with('title', 'Browse Movies');
  }
}
```

Javascript File
    $(function() {
      $('.movie').click(function() {
        $('.details').load(this.href);
          return false;
      });
    });

[The project can be found here](https://github.com/bryansattler/rhubarb)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your using the wrong "this"-operator. Should be "$(this)" if it's is a jQuery scripts? (The JavaScript part...)

Also: Ur telling it to add the result from ".load()" into the ".details", but I can't see that you have such a field in your html code?

**EDIT**

Change the following in /application/views/browse/index.blade.php:

```
echo '<li class="movieCardInfo"><a href="movie" class="movie">' . $movie->title . '</a></li>';

echo '<li class="movieCardInfo"><a href="movie" class="movie">' . $movie->title . '</a><div class="details"></div></li>';
```

And remove the "div.details" from the response, so the response only returns the text you want in your details.

Then, in the the JavaScript:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.movie').click(function() {
        $('.details').load($(this).href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks 2rsvold. I have it in my movie.blade.php file. For some reason the code isn't showing up.

here it is:

    echo '<div class="details">';
   echo '<p>test</p>';
    echo '</div>';

Comment: and yes, it is for jQuery.

Comment: Laravel doesn't seem to be recognizing my route for movie.

I was able to make the text replace the #browse div with html like this:

$(".movie").click(function(){  $("#browse").html("test") });


Now the trick is being able to grab the movie ID from the Rotten Tomatoes API and pass it into the javascript function along with the php to create the view of the movie details.

I believe I'll have to restructure my app so the API can be called globally.

My project is here:

https://github.com/bryansattler/rhubarb